# How to find $\int\limits_0^b \frac{x}{b-x}e^{a(b-x)}dx$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, limits, analysis

I am not sure how to find:

$$\int\limits_0^b \frac{x}{b-x}e^{a(b-x)}dx$$

where $b$ is an integer and $a$ is not with $a,b>0$. I've tried integration by parts to no logical end and know that $\int\limits_0^{\infty} x^n e^{-ax} = \frac{\Gamma(n+1)}{a^{n+1}}$ but am not sure if I can reduce the integral to such a form. Any ideas?

Comment: This integral does not converge for any choice of $a,b$. Consider $x\to b^-$ then the integrand behaves like $b/(b-x)$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Note that if $a,b>0$ then
$$\int_0^b \frac{x}{b-x}e^{a(b-x)}dx\geq \int_0^b \frac{x}{b-x}dx=
\int_{0}^b \frac{b-t}{t}dt=[b\log(t)-t]_0^{b}=+\infty.$$

Answer (score 2):

Hint: this can be simplified to:

$$\int \frac{x}{b-x}e^{a(b-x)}dx =
\int \left(\frac{b}{b-x} - 1\right)e^{a(b-x)}dx=
b\int \frac{e^{ay}}{y}dy - \int e^{ay}dy=$$

But the choice of limit make it infinite.