# How to find the following integral:

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

$$\int_0^b \frac{x}{b-x}\left[ e^{a_1(b-x)} - e^{a_2(b-x)}\right]$$

where $a_1>a_2>0, b>0$. I can see that $\int_0^b \frac{x}{b-x} e^{a_1(b-x)} = \infty$ from a question I asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3585915/how-to-find-int-limits-0b-fracxb-xeab-xdx) and am wondering if this integral converges and how to find it?

Comment: Let $u=b-x$, $x = u+b$, to get $$\int_0^b\frac{u+b}{u}\left[e^{a_1u}-e^{a_2u}\right]\;du$$
This integrand looks like it might be put into the form $C(u+b)e^{pu}\frac{\sinh qu}{u}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The integral obviously converges.  The integrand is $x\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{a_1^k-a_2^k}{k!}(b-x)^{k-1}\lt \frac{x}{b}e^{a_1b}$  Therefore the integral $\lt \frac{b}{2}e^{a_1b}$.

Comment: I see, that's true. May I know how to find the integral? I know I didn't ask that in the original question, editing it now.

Comment: Unlikely: the indefinite integral (using MPW commmment) is $\int\frac{e^{ax}}{x}dx=Ei(ax)$, and it doesn't simplify.